# Get the quote/order ID that the user checked out?

Tags: checkout, orders

I need to get the actual order id that the customer is using creating an order.
Tried with this that works fine, but returns me the previous order id, I need to get the actual one:

```
    $last_order_increment_id = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()->getLastItem()->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: I achived it with this code.. not sure if there's a better option:
  $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
  $lastorderId = $orderId + 1;